# Stanford Corenlp: Regexner unexpectedly overwrites NER entities

Tags: stanford-nlp

I have the phrase:

`5th-6th Grade Teacher, Mount Pilot Elementary School`

RegExner mapping file contents:

`Pilot   TITLE`

Annotators:

`tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,depparse,ner,regexner`

Everything works fine with such configuration, I get the phrase "Mount Pilot Elementary School" tagged as ORGANIZATION, and in the corenlp log I have a message:

`Not annotating  'Pilot': ORGANIZATION with [TITLE], sentence is '5th-6th Grade Teacher , Mount Pilot Elementary School'`

So this is OK and expected behaviour.

However once I add the follwing line to the mapping file:

`Labor   ORGANIZATION`

CoreNLP returns such tags for the same santence:

`Mount/ORGANIZATION
Pilot/TITLE
Elementary School/ORGANIZATION`

"Pilot" ORGANIZATION get overwrited by "Pilot" TITLE from the mapping file.

Is there any way to avoid this behaviour? I just wanted to tag "Labor" as an ORGANIZATION, I didn't want to force CoreNLP overwrite NER tags by RegexNER. In my opinion it is a bit unexpected, but maybe this is kind of a feature than a bug

Answer (score 0):

Your rule needs to be in this format:

```
Pilot   TITLE   MISC    1
```

Then it will not overwrite other label types.

Comment: it seems this has not helped, now my mapping file is:

Pilot   TITLE   MISC    1
Labor   ORGANIZATION

I run the command:
java -cp "*" -Xmx2g edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP -annotators tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner,regexner -regexner.mapping /data/regexner/regexner.txt -file input.txt

input.txt contains the phrase from the question

And the output for "Pilot" is still:

[Text=Pilot CharacterOffsetBegin=29 CharacterOffsetEnd=34 PartOfSpeech=NN Lemma=pilot NamedEntityTag=TITLE]

Comment: by the way, I run the latest CoreNLP version from the master branch

Comment: During looking through the TokenRegexNERAnnotator code I found out that the replacement is forced by this condition https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/blob/d558d95d80b36b5b45bc21882cbc0ef7452eda24/src/edu/stanford/nlp/pipeline/TokensRegexNERAnnotator.java#L510-L512, so I added the  "-regexner.noDefaultOverwriteLabels TITLE" configuration option and everything started to work as I expect. Thank you for your help @StanfordNLPHelp! Could you update your answer to note the "noDefaultOverwriteLabels" option, so I can mark your answer as the solution?

Comment: I ran with the latest code on your example and did not require noDefaultOverwriteLabels.  I should note there should be a "\t" in between each column of my example rule.

Comment: hm, ok I will try it again with a fresh corenlp copy. yes I know about \t.

Comment: I just tried it again with the fresh copy of CoreNLP and the latest models and got the same(unexpected) result. @StanfordNLPHelp please take a look at my reproduction steps https://docs.google.com/document/d/1b1ieoS72CwOwllnY7sW2AN7A8htSx-0sUZ4cWFyIVP0/edit?usp=sharing.

Comment: I faced this issue; it was missing #CLASSPATH and models; comments here: https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/issues/983#issuecomment-573536392